# Get the file-descriptor from dirent field d_name(filename)

Tags: c, linux, systems-programming

Is there a way to obtain `file-descriptors` for the `filenames` obtained from `dirent` field `d_name`.

Comment: `int fd = openat(dirfd, dirent->d_name, FLAGS);`?

Comment: Make that `int fd = openat(dirfd(dirp), dirent->d_name, FLAGS);` where `dirp` is the `DIR *` returned by the relevant `opendir()` call.